# C++|Storing user input to template variables

Tags: c++, templates, input

I want somehow to remove all restrictions from input, what I mean:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
```

this allows the user to "answer" only with an integer, if the user writes a string as an input, either nothing or errors happen, if the "answer" is a float or double the number will be converted to int and data will be lost. 
I want to solve that problem, I remembered templates that allow you to do functions more generic you do not need to care that much about data types, so I thought that I could use that to input and make input more generic, freer, but it does not work even if I make the function that does the input a method.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class C {
    public:
    T x;
    void f(){
        std::cin >> x;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    C obj;
    obj.f();
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
error: use of class template 'C' requires template arguments
        C obj;
        ^
<stdin>:4:7: note: template is declared here
class C {
```

If you know or you can imagine something please consider answering to my question, anything as long as it gives the results I want, the knowledge I seek its considered a solution (if possible not too long in lines of code && not too complicated)

Comment: No, templates don't work this way. C++ does not work this way. You will need to read input into a plain text string, a `std::string`, then parse the string and figure out what's been read, an integer, a floating point value, or something else, based on the individual characters in the string, then convert it to the appropriate variable. You will have to do all this work and write a bunch of code yourself. C++ will not do it for you. There's very little in C++ that happens automatically, like this. You will always need to do all the work yourself.

Comment: Why not input into a `double` variable instead of an `int`? Then you can later convert to an `int` if it is an integer

Comment: Templates are evaluated at compile-time(i.e. the executable doesn't even exist yet). You can only get user input at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the declaration `C obj;` basically makes no sense, as `C` is a template class. As an example, this would be like declaring `std::vector vec;` instead of `std::vector<int> vec;`. But apart from that, `std::cin` will not put whatever input it gets into whatever variable it gets. You would need to get the input into a string, then parse it. For this, I suggest making a separate singleton that overloads `operator>>()`.